# paintComponent question

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

What purpose does super.paintComponent(g) serve in this sample code?

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(gridX * 50, gridY * 50, 50, 50);
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < 10; j++) {
            if (savedTiles[i][j])
                g.fillRect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes sure that the parent component paints first

Comment: Can yuz put here complete class? super is http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html ...

Comment: @Kaj, it has nothing to do with the "parent". It invokes the default functionality of the component first, before adding customizations. In this case I would guess a JPanel is being overridden, in which case the default functionality it to paint the background of the component. Once that is done the custom code paints rectangles on top of the background.

Comment: Ok, I agree that it could be misinterpreted. I wasn't talking about the layout and component hierarchy, to me the panel that he extended is the parent (i.e super)

Comment: (That is, I was talking about inheritance hierarchy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

super tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 0):

That is dependent upon what super class you override the `paintComponent`-method from. But as a answer it has the purpose of calling the super class version of the same method before the overriden is run.